# Thermal Conductance along the lateral and longitudinal direction

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, phonon-dispersion, lattice-thermal-conductivity, nonequilibrium

Suppose the left and right leads are both copper rod and the central scattering region is one monolayer graphene sheet. There is no chemical bonding formed between Cu and C atoms. The copper and graphene are connected by the Van der Waals interaction.

Is the non equilibrium green function (NEGF) method applicable for the thermal conductance calculation along both lateral and longitudinal direction for such system?

Would anyone please give me some suggestions?

Thank you in advance.